# Scheduled task to save my notebook every 30 seconds?

Tags: notebooks, crash, save

I keep crashing Mathematica and losing cells and textual data that I'm typing. Instead of having to remember to hit command+s all the time, I'd like a scheduled task to save my notebook every 30 seconds, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

This [seems to do the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7193804/4712538)

```
saveTask = 
  CreateScheduledTask[FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["Save"]], 30];
StartScheduledTask[saveTask]
```

[This also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6982126/4712538),

```
Dynamic[Refresh[NotebookSave[]; DateString[], UpdateInterval -> 30]]
```

Of course, there's also this built-in functionality with

```
SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave -> True]
```